# How to save an NxNxN array (or Matrix) into a file in Julia (or Python)?

Tags: multidimensional-array, save, julia

I'm working on a Jupyter notebook and currently using Julia

I'm trying to save a 3x3x3 Array into a textfile so when I include it in another notebook, the array is a 3x3x3 Array too.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need it to be in plain text? If not, you might want to look at the HDF5.jl package.

Comment: You can save values using `writecsv`/`readcsv`, but not dimensions or type (integers will be parsed as floating points). Don't know if you mind casting and reshaping. `convert(Array{Int64}, reshape( readcsv("vals"), 3, 3, 3))`

Comment: I was using `writecsv`, but as you said, it didn't save dimensions or type. I looked at the HDF5.jl package and it was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: See also [What is the correct way to save and retrieve dictionaries in Julia?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013516/what-is-the-correct-way-to-save-and-retrieve-dictionaries-in-julia)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use the [JLD.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl) (Julia Data) package:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("JLD")
using JLD
r = rand(3, 3, 3)
save("data.jld", "data", r)
load("data.jld")["data"]
```

> The advantage of the JLD package is that it preserves the **exact** type information of each variable.

Comment: Don't forget ``Pkg.add("JLD")``

Comment: Where does the file get saved? Can I change the directory of where it is saved?

Comment: @newtothis sure, just pass the full or relative path, it will save by default in the current working directory.

Answer (score 9):

Okay I admit that I am a python lover, though Julia is starting to grow on me. So as an old python user there is a Julia package that can convert arrays into numpy npz files and then read them as well. Example:

```
    x = reshape(1:27, 3,3,3)
    Pkg.add("NPZ")
    using NPZ
    npzwrite("TEST.npz",x)
```

And now I can later load this file (so long as I am using the NPZ package):

```
    y = npzread("TEST.npz")
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the HDF5.jl package for storing my Arrays as it saves dimensions and type. I believe it's almost the same as NPZ but HDF5 has a proper Julia data extension (.jld) so it works better for me