# What is the correct way to save and retrieve dictionaries in Julia?

Tags: file, parsing, julia

I have seen that Julia adequately interprets "MAT" files which have structures in them which are read as dictionaries without problem. Now I have created a dictionary of my own, which has the following structure

```
(String, String)=> [ Int, Int, Int]
```

on each entry. I can save it with `writedlm` and it produces a very orderly
tabular text file, separated by tabs (`\t`), but then I cannot retrieve it without doing a LOT of parsing. If I use `readdlm` I get an array of type `Any`, with the very uncomfortable structure at each line

```
"(\"Bla bla\", \"tururu\")"     "[a, b, c]"
```

That is, two columns of `String`s which contain signs such as `'"'` and `'['`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the actual code that you used to produce these results.

Comment: You could definitely save back to a MAT file, although is reccomend using the HDF5 package and the JLD submodule. JLD was written to store arbitrary Julia data types (even user defined ones).

Comment: See also [How to save an NxNxN array (or Matrix) into a file in Julia (or Python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926050/how-to-save-an-nxnxn-array-or-matrix-into-a-file-in-julia-or-python/31205562#31205562)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `JLD` (Julia Data) submodule included in the [`HDF5`](https://github.com/timholy/HDF5.jl) package:

```
Pkg.add("HDF5")
using HDF5, JLD
d = Dict(
    ("a", "b") => [1, 2, 3],
    ("c", "d") => [4, 5, 6],
    ("e", "f") => [7, 8, 9]
)
save("data.jld", "data", d)
load("data.jld")["data"]
```

> the advantage of the JLD module is that it preserves the **exact** type information of each variable.

Answer (score 4):

The solution using JLD suggested by SalchiPapa no longer works for some reason. Here is an updated version (just changed the imports and the file extension) of their example using JLD2:

```
using JLD2, FileIO
d = Dict(
        ("a", "b") => [1, 2, 3],
        ("c", "d") => [4, 5, 6],
        ("e", "f") => [7, 8, 9]
    )
save("data.jld2", "data", d)
load("data.jld2")["data"]
```